# Как пишутся названия замковых/крепостных стен и ворот?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, литература, топонимика

Скажите, пожалуйста, если у стен и ворот вымышленного замка/крепости или даже отдельно стоящих стен есть свои названия, то они же подчиняются правилу о написании географических названий? То есть все слова в таких названиях, кроме родовых и служебных, пишутся с прописной, как, например, Спасская башня, башня Белого Золота, Грозовые ворота, врата Мещан? В замке есть стена Боли, Ратная стена, Черная стена, стена Павших Влюбленных, Старые ворота, Грязные ворота, ворота Короля Блауда и пр.

Comment: В русских названиях в большинстве башня - не будет родовым, а будет собственно башней с прилагательным в виде названия. А вот в английском будет наоборот, родовое слово и понятие-название. За исключением более редких башен в честь кого-то, Угловая Арсенальная башня (Собакина) - но как видно, что башня Собакина - это не основное название. Я считаю, большинство русским топонимов или названий начинаются с притяжательных прилагательных а заканчиваются существительным типа сооружения, постройки и тп., которое не является родовым.

Comment: Также думаю, китайские топонимы и названия будут иметь такое же расположение слов. Великая Китайская стена - по-китайски это "длинная стена", последнее слово главное, а остальные прилагательные, а вот в английском появляется предлог Great Wall of China - то есть Великая стена Китая. Также стоит отметить, что в английском название чего-то знаменитого не будет содержать родового слова, так как это будет general(главное) noun а не generic(родовое). Родовое это или a cat или the cat, а general - это или Cat для ряда понятий можно с маленькой beauty.

Comment: Так вот, если это родовое слово, то это the cat of Monday. В русском видимо предлог опускается, но расположение слов остаётся. А general noun это North Atlantic Ocean, Second World War. В русском будет вторая мировая война или Вторая мировая война, то есть в русском регистр не обязателен для формирования не родовых названий.

Comment: Поэтому Петроград, а град Петра - это нехарактерное название в сторону родового град.

Comment: Очень интересные комментарии, нельзя ли их перенести  в поле ответа? Пометить, что это не конкретный ответ на заданный вопрос, а сравнение названий в разных языках. А я  могу дать стандартный ответ))  Но он не так интересен.

Comment: @Sharon я попытался написать что-то более менее адекватное, но получилось такое полотенце, что лучше это не публиковать, но суть в целом именно такая, как в комментариях, как мне кажется.